# ng-include and ng-repeat - remove child

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm probably just stroking out, but I'm having trouble with the following little piece of code. I've got nested ng-repeats and ng-includes and want to remove an item from an arbitrary level of nesting. Sooo...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in List" ng-include="'item.html'">
</div>
```

**item.html**

```
<div>
   <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
   <div ng-repeat="item in item.List" ng-include="'item.html'"></div>
   <button ng-click="removeItem(item)">Remove me!</button>
</div>
```

Obviously if I could access the parent's `List` array I could splice'r out based on the index, but I'm having serious brain fog about how to access that parent object. Any idea how I could pass the parent into the ng-include along with the `item`?

Comment: could you provide demo in plunker/fiddle that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Can you flesh out your scenario a bit more?  Using `ng-include` to create recursion like this is pretty uncommon, and generally confusing.  `$parent` ***might*** do what you want, but could get messy;  code that is `$parent.$parent.$parent` gets really ugly really quick.

Comment: There's not much more to flesh out. An item needs to be able to remove itself from it's parent's `List` array, so it wouldn't need to go more than a level above. I've tried `$parent`, but it doesn't expose the List array, just the parent controller. What better way is there to do recursion like this?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how I could pass the parent into the ng-include along with the item?

I think to pass parent to child will cause to code complexibility and hard maintenance. I also belaive it can effect on performance when we talk about big data.  You don't use nested directive with isolate scope so I would use  other approach to remove node from nested tree based on unique value a.e.:

```
function removeFromTree(parent, childNameToRemove){
      console.log(parent);
           parent.nodes = parent.nodes.filter(function(child){ 
             return child.name !== childNameToRemove;
           }).map(function(child){ 
              return removeFromTree(child, childNameToRemove);
           });
    return parent;
   }


    $scope.removeItem = function(item){
       $scope.displayTree[0] = removeFromTree( $scope.displayTree[0], item.name);
    }
```

<kbd>**[Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iMb8tFugtwbHTUq9J1x7?p=preview)**</kbd>

---

#### Full code

*HTML*

```
<div ng-controller="DialogDemoCtrl">
          <div class="span5 article-tree">
          <div ng-style="{'overflow': 'auto'}">

            <script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer">
              <span>
                 {{showNode(data)}} 
              </span>
             <button ng-click="removeItem(data)">Remove me!</button>
              <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" class="parent_li"  ng-include="'tree_item_renderer'" tree-node></li>
              </ul>
            </script>

            <div class="tree well">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="data in displayTree"  ng-include="'tree_item_renderer'"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('DialogDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

     buildEmptyTree();   


    function removeFromTree(parent, childNameToRemove){
      console.log(parent);
           parent.nodes = parent.nodes.filter(function(child){ 
             return child.name !== childNameToRemove;
           }).map(function(child){ 
              return removeFromTree(child, childNameToRemove);
           });
    return parent;
   }


    $scope.removeItem = function(item){
       $scope.displayTree[0] = removeFromTree( $scope.displayTree[0], item.name);
    }        

 function buildEmptyTree() {

        $scope.displayTree =
            [{
            "name": "Root",
            "type_name": "Node",
            "show": true,
            "nodes": [{
                "name": "Loose",
                "group_name": "Node-1",
                "show": true,
                "nodes": [{
                    "name": "Node-1-1",
                    "device_name": "Node-1-1",
                    "show": true,
                    "nodes": []
                }, {
                    "name": "Node-1-2",
                    "device_name": "Node-1-2",
                    "show": true,
                    "nodes": []
                }, {
                    "name": "Node-1-3",
                    "device_name": "Node-1-3",
                    "show": true,
                    "nodes": []
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "God",
                "group_name": "Node-2",
                "show": true,
                "nodes": [{
                    "name": "Vadar",
                    "device_name": "Node-2-1",
                    "show": true,
                    "nodes": []
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Borg",
                "group_name": "Node-3",
                "show": true,
                "nodes": []
            }, {
                "name": "Fess",
                "group_name": "Node-4",
                "show": true,
                "nodes": []
            }]
        }];
        [{
            "name": "Android",
            "type_name": "Android",
            "icon": "icon-android icon-3",
            "show": true,
            "nodes": []
        }];
    }        
});
```

Comment: I thought about this approach, but using a guid instead of the name field. It's feeling like this is the cleanest approach, but I'd rather not throw extra data in there.

Comment: @opticon you can use unique id, it will give you flexibility and easy code maintenance. Otherwise, to pass parent to child - is overkill